# How to stop OpenGL support from OpenCV compiled libraries 

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv, macros

I compiled new version of opencv along opengl support. I thought it will help me opengl related work along opencv.

```
cv::Mat jk = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\ssc1\\Documents\\hair-2.png",0);
cv::imshow("xxxx",jk);


cv::waitKey();
```

this is my small code without an opengl stuff but its crashing at the end due to openGL support. It by default assuming that i am using opengl window.

Inside header file  window_w32.cpp of opencv

```
#ifdef HAVE_OPENGL
if (window->useGl)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(window->dc, window->hGLRC);
```

its crashing on this code.

i tried using #undef HAVE_OPENGL but it didnt help ...does it mean i should recompile without the support of OpenGL and use it with explicit opengl libraries when i need them?

Guide me what i am making mistake.

Comment: did you compile with Qt or GTK support?

Comment: no i am not using QT , is opengl support is dependent on QT or GTK?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenCV and OpenGL in a windows environment, but trying adding CV_WINDOW_NORMAL as the second argument in your namedWindow() function.